# UITextView with multi line headline

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitextview, textfield

I faced with the following challenge. I want to make a very first line of text view like a headline. It should be multi line until user tap return button. This is the exact behaviour of Apple Notes view.
[image]
I already walked through lots of topics here, articles and libs and didn’t find anything suitable.

Could you please provide me with ideas how to implement similar behaviour or recommend me a library as an alternative.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would look into TextKit. This is a framework that allows you to setup a text and the way text is presented.

Comment: Are you trying to make a text editor where you allow the user to change fonts/sizes, colors, other formatting options? Or do you just want the first line (up to newline char) to be one font size/style and the rest to be a second font size/style?

Comment: @DonMag Yes, you're totally right. I just want to get the first line as headline up to newline and the rest of the text just as regular one.

Comment: @Suprafen thanks a lot, I'll take a closer look at this framework.

Answer (score 0):

I've only done very quick testing with this, and it doesn't work **exactly** like Apple Notes, but it may be sufficient for your needs.

```
class FirstLineFormatVC: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
    
    let tv = UITextView()
    
    let firstLineAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [
        .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20.0, weight: .bold),
    ]

    let normalAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [
        .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16.0, weight: .regular),
    ]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(tv)

        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            tv.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            tv.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            tv.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            tv.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300.0),

        ])
    
        tv.delegate = self
        
        // give it a background color so we can see it
        tv.backgroundColor = .yellow
        
    }

    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        //formatTextInTextView(textView: textView)

        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        let selectedRange = textView.selectedRange
        let text = textView.text ?? ""
        
        // set full string to normalAttributes
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text, attributes: normalAttributes)
        
        // get the first line
        let range = text.lineRange(for: ..<text.startIndex)
        let nsRange = NSRange(range, in: text)
        
        // set first line to firstLineAttributes
        attributedString.addAttributes(firstLineAttributes, range: nsRange)
        
        // update the attributedText
        textView.attributedText = attributedString
        textView.selectedRange = selectedRange
        textView.isScrollEnabled = true

    }

}
```

Hopefully it's at least a starting point.